# TSQL: Create row per period depending on start - end date based on existing rows

Tags: sql-server, date, t-sql, datetime

I have the following table with Cars. People have a standard Car, but sometimes (When a car goes into a garage or is damaged) they get another car. In my country you have to pay tax for driving a company car, so it's important WHEN a car is driven and WHICH car is driven. If the spare car is a cheaper car, you pay less tax in that period.

The table is not that difficult:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.CARUSAGE
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    StartDate datetime NULL,
    EndDate datetime NULL,
    CarID int NULL,
    UserID int NULL,
    TypeID int NULL
);

INSERT dbo.CARUSAGE (StartDate, EndDate, CarID, UserID, TypeID) 
VALUES ('2020-04-19', NULL, 2, 2606, 1)
       ,('2020-07-07', '2020-10-07', 3, 2606, 2)
       ,('2020-10-12', '2020-10-31', 4, 2606, 2)
```

TypeIDs:
TypeID 1 = Standard.
TypeID 2 = Spare.

Standard cars are like a thread. You have always a standard car unless you use a spare.

EndDate standard car is NULL when still driving.

I Like to achieve a result set like this:

```
+----------+--------+---------+---------+-------------+-------------+
|  NewID  |  CarID |  UserID |  TypeID |   StartDate |     EndDate |
+----------+--------+---------+---------+-------------+-------------+
|        1 |      2 |    2606 |       1 | 2020-04-19  | 2020-07-06  |
|        2 |      3 |    2606 |       2 | 2020-07-07  | 2020-10-06  |
|        3 |      2 |    2606 |       1 | 2020-10-07  | 2020-10-11  |
|        4 |      4 |    2606 |       2 | 2020-10-12  | 2020-10-30  |
|        5 |      2 |    2606 |       1 | 2020-10-31  | GetDate()   |
|          |        |         |         |             |             |
+----------+--------+---------+---------+-------------+-------------+
```

**An additional question based on above:**

Although GMB answered my question very well I forgot to mention one thing which makes the query a little bit more complicated.

It's possible to add a new 'standard' car. When a new 'standard' car is added then the original 'standard' car gets an end date. The source table looks like:

```sql
INSERT dbo.CARUSAGE (StartDate, EndDate, CarID, UserID, TypeID) 
VALUES ('2020-04-19', '2020-11-04', 2, 2606, 1)
       ,('2020-07-07', '2020-10-07', 3, 2606, 2)
       ,('2020-10-12', '2020-10-31', 4, 2606, 2)
       ,('2020-11-05', null, 5, 2606, 1)
       ,('2020-11-09', '2020-11-14', 6, 2606, 2)
```

The proces needs to be the same. There is *always* a 'standard' car.
The select result would be looking like this

```
+----------+--------+---------+---------+-------------+-------------+
|  NewID  |  CarID |  UserID |  TypeID |   StartDate |     EndDate |
+----------+--------+---------+---------+-------------+-------------+
|        1 |      2 |    2606 |       1 | 2020-04-19  | 2020-07-06  |
|        2 |      3 |    2606 |       2 | 2020-07-07  | 2020-10-06  |
|        3 |      2 |    2606 |       1 | 2020-10-07  | 2020-10-11  |
|        4 |      4 |    2606 |       2 | 2020-10-12  | 2020-10-30  |
|        5 |      2 |    2606 |       1 | 2020-10-31  | 2020-11-04  |
|        6 |      5 |    2606 |       1 | 2020-11-05  | 2020-11-08  |
|        7 |      6 |    2606 |       2 | 2020-11-09  | 2020-11-13  |
|        8 |      5 |    2606 |       1 | 2020-11-14  | GetDate()   |
+----------+--------+---------+---------+-------------+-------------+
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI, Tables don't have "records", they have columns and rows, and specific column in a specific row has a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you can unpivot the start and end dates, and fill the "gaps" with spare records, like so:

```
select t.carid, c.userid,t.typeid, t.dt as startdt,
    lead(dateadd(day, -1, t.dt), 1, convert(date, getdate())) over(partition by c.userid order by t.dt) as enddt
from carusage c
cross apply (select carid from carusage c1 where c1.userid = c.userid and c1.typeid = 1) s
cross apply (values (c.startdate, c.typeid, c.carid), (c.enddate, 1, s.carid)) t(dt, typeid, carid)
where t.dt is not null
order by t.dt
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/markdown?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f64201f380e6e622bfc4225e9c50f442)**:

```
carid | userid | typeid | startdt                 | enddt                  
----: | -----: | -----: | :---------------------- | :----------------------
    2 |   2606 |      1 | 2020-04-19 00:00:00.000 | 2020-07-06 00:00:00.000
    3 |   2606 |      2 | 2020-07-07 00:00:00.000 | 2020-10-06 00:00:00.000
    2 |   2606 |      1 | 2020-10-07 00:00:00.000 | 2020-10-11 00:00:00.000
    4 |   2606 |      2 | 2020-10-12 00:00:00.000 | 2020-10-30 00:00:00.000
    2 |   2606 |      1 | 2020-10-31 00:00:00.000 | 2020-11-20 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Hi GMB. Can you please look into the addition of my question. It seems that you're the only one with answers.